# Make server globally reachable on IPv6

Tags: networking, network-manager, iptables, ipv6, hosting

I've been hosting a globally-reachable Minecraft server on my desktop Ubuntu computer at home for about 1 month, on IPv4, using my ISP's router NAT configuration.

Recently, my ISP (SFR, a French company) decided to completely remove the NAT configuration from the web config panel, breaking all my setup. The change was confirmed by a lot of clients on support forums. I have absolutely no idea of how IPv6 works, but I don't have much choice but to use it if I want to keep my server up and running.

I've read a bit about IPv6 and contrarily to IPv4, it seems like IPv6 addresses are all "global" and thus, there's no equivalent to NAT, so I'm pretty sure that I don't have to configure anything on my router.
However, after experimenting, only my roommate was able to join the server, meaning that packets from outside my LAN are probably filtered by some firewall somewhere. Second problem: the `ifconfig` IPv6 address of my computer (on ethernet) changes after every reboot. I could use a dynamic domain service, but it seems like overkill as there's probably a way to have a fixed IPv6 address like with IPv4. I tried adding

```
iface enp37s0 inet6 static
pre-up modprobe ipv6
address 2a02:842a:3aa:f301:b036:c7cb:8cce:35ad
netmask 64
```

to my interfaces files but after restarting the network service, I still add my previous IPv6 address.

To sum up, as a complete newbie in IPv6, I wanted to know:

- In case the outside-packet filtering is done by a firewall on my computer itself (which it probably is, if my understanding is correct), which part of Linux/Ubuntu manages that ? How to allow packets sent to a given port ?
- Can I pin(/ make static) an IPv6 address ?

Comment: On IPv6 there are also addresses that are local only. You need the address that contains the IPv6 prefix the router got from your ISP check your public IPv6 addr  using websites like whatsmyip.com. Yes IPv6 in router usually means no NAT but traffic may still be blocked by an IPv6 firewall. In the end if you can I would simply suggest to use your own router.

Comment: Thank you @Robert , I'll search a bit about that.